# Is my salary haram after attesting that I've never been convicted by a court of law, when I was fined for entering a train platform without a ticket?

Tags: halal-haram, work, lying

When joining a government organization, there was a question while filling the attestation form that have you ever been convicted by a court of law for any offence. I wrote no. Actually I had been fined by an rpf court of law for entering into the railway platform without platform ticket.

During the time of filling the application form somebody told me it's just a petty case already closed so no need to mention. So I did it.

Will my salary be halal or haram?

Comment: Is the focus of this question about determining whether what you did amounts to lying, or about whether lying can render one's salary haram?

Comment: Huh, where did you come up with the fact that if one lies it will render one's salary haram?

Comment: Getting fined by the police (without the courts direction) and being convicted in a law court are different things.

Comment: I think your answer to write no was correct. A fine is not the same as convicted by a court. Do you look for a general answer on whether the salary was haram if you really had lied?

Answer (score -1):

Honesty is the best policy. If you are being dishonest in acquiring something let that be acquiring a job, its not justifiable to fabricate or lie.

> And do not mix the truth with falsehood or conceal the truth while you know
>
> Quran 2:42

Therefore, anything that comes as a result of a prohibited deed is also considered prohibited.